# Pulling information from a document and adding to excel with PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell, ms-word, powershell-4.0

I'm quite new to PowerShell and don't really know if what i'm looking for is possible. I need to create a Script which will pull information from word documents. These will be strings of information spread out throughout the document and in different locations from time to time. Once gathered all these strings I'd like to add them to an Excel Sheet. Is that something that's possible using PowerShell? I'm having a hard time trying to find information which talks about searching for information in a document and pull that information instead of more "meta data".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can start with `open-xml-powertools` for manipulating word documents

https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools

for excel there are plenty of powershell libraries and scripts available so just go to `powershellgallery` or `github` and search for excel.